# WordPress Password Protected Custom Page Template

Tags: wordpress

I am having a custom page template on WordPress and also the [Password Protected plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/password-protected/) installed. When I set the page to password protected, nothing happens and the page is still visible for all users.

[This is how I set Password Protected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7sD2.png)

Comment: Are you logged in with an admin user?

Comment: No, I open the page in a brand new incognito tab and it is still available, although I have protected it with a password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you share some more info about the page template?

EDIT:

You can try pasting something like this after your get_header() function in the template:

```
if ( post_password_required() ) {
    echo get_the_password_form();
    get_footer();
    return;
}
```

Comment: It is a flexible page template, but I don't think this should matter. It's just being selected from the Page Template dropdown as other templates.

Comment: Take a look at the edit and see if that works